# KeyboardSpecialFunc cant rotate opengl python

Tags: python, glut, pyopengl

I'm working on an OpenGL project for school and I dont know how to figure out my 'error'.
Let me explain:

I have the function `glutKeyboardFunc` who take the callback of my function  `keyboard`.
In this function, when I press the p letter (for example), I can rotate my camera with this:

```
elif key == 'p':
    moveY = (moveY + 1) % 360
    glRotatef(moveY, 1, 0, 0)
```

This is working

Then I wanted to use the arrow (right, left...)
So I used the `glutSpecialFunc` and my callback function `special_keyboard`
I know that the key's right arrow as the 102 integer (I printed it)
But when I write the same thing for the letter p, nothing happen.

```
elif key == 102: # Right Arrow
    moveY = (moveY + 1) % 360
    glRotatef(moveY, 1, 0, 0)
```

I've tried many things but still doesn't work.

If someone has a solution :)
Thanks all

Here is my code:

This is my entire code

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

###############################################################
import sys
import math
try:
    from OpenGL.GL import *  # exception car prefixe systematique
    from OpenGL.GLU import *
    from OpenGL.GLUT import *
except:
    print("Pas de module pour OpenGL")
    print("pip install pyopengl")
    sys.exit(1)


###############################################################
# variables globales
move_pos_x, angle_canon, move_pos_z = 0, 2, 1.8
moveX, moveY, moveZ = 0, 0, 0 # utilisé pour la caméra
pas_zoom = 0
quadric = None

test = 0

def init():
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH)

    light()
    camera()


    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)

def light():
    """
    Fournis la lumière dans le programme
    """
    # Création des listes pour les couleurs
    red = [1, 0, 0, 1]
    white = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
    diffuse = [0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 1.0]
    specular = [0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 1.0]
    pos = [10, 10, 1, 1]

    # On crée la lumière
    # glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE, red)
    # glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SPECULAR, white)
    # glMaterialf(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SHININESS, 7.0)

    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING)
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0)
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, pos)
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, diffuse)
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPECULAR, specular)

def draw_canon():
    """
    Fonction qui dessine le canon
    Le canon est constitué de 3 parties: le canon ainsi que 2 roues
    """
    # On place un cylindre ==> canon

    glRotatef(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
    glTranslatef(move_pos_x, 0.15, move_pos_z)
    glRotatef(angle_canon, 0.5, 0.0, 0.0)
    glMaterial(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE, [1, 1, 1, 0])
    glRotatef(180, 0, 0, 0)
    glutSolidCylinder(0.05, 0.3, 70, 70)

    # On place un tore ==> roue droite du canon
    glRotatef(90, 0, 1.0, 0.0)
    glTranslatef(0, 0.0, 0.06)
    glRotatef(0, 0.5, 0.0, 0.0)
    glTranslatef(-0.2, 0, 0)
    glMaterial(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE, [1, 0, 0, 1])
    glutSolidTorus(0.01, 0.03, 70, 70)

    # Seconde roue du canon
    glRotatef(0, 0, 1.0, 0.0)
    glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, -0.12)
    glRotatef(0, 0.5, 0.0, 0.0)
    glMaterial(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE, [1, 0, 0, 1])
    glutSolidTorus(0.01, 0.03, 70, 70)

def draw_scene():
    """
    Fonction qui dessine la scène du jeu.
    La scène est constitué de 3 parties: 2 berges de couleurs jaune séparé par de l'eau au milieu
    """
    glPushMatrix()
    # On scale pour modifier les cubes
    glScalef(3, 0.2, 0.5)
    # Berge du fond de couleur jaune
    glMaterial(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE, [1, 1, 0, 1])
    glutSolidCube(1)
    glPopMatrix()

    # On dessine le cube cible
    glPushMatrix()
    glTranslatef(0, 0.15, 0)
    glMaterial(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE, [1, 0, 0, 1])
    glutSolidCube(0.1)
    glPopMatrix()


    glPushMatrix()
    # On translate pour placer l'eau
    glTranslatef(0, -0.1, 1)
    glScalef(3, 0.2, 1.5)
    # L'eau au milieu, qui est plus grand que les berges
    glMaterial(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE, [0, 0, 1, 1])
    glutSolidCube(1)
    glPopMatrix()

    glPushMatrix()
    # On translate pour placer la dernière berge
    glTranslatef(0, 0, 2)
    glScalef(3, 0.2, 0.5)
    # Dernière berge
    glMaterial(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE, [1, 1, 0, 1])
    glutSolidCube(1)

    glPopMatrix()

def camera():
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
    glLoadIdentity()
    glRotatef(30, 2, 0, 0)
    viewMatrix = glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX)

def display():

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

    glPushMatrix()

    draw_scene()

    draw_canon()

    glPopMatrix()

    glutSwapBuffers()


def keyboard(key, x, y):
    global move_pos_x, move_pos_z
    global angle_canon
    global moveX, moveY, moveZ
    global test
    # On bouge le cyclindre canon de haut en bas
    try:
        key = key.decode()
    except UnicodeDecodeError: # avoid decode error when pressing key
        pass
    if key == "a":
        angle_canon = (angle_canon + 1) % 30
        test += 0.1
        """
        if angle_canon != 29:
            angle_canon = (angle_canon + 1) % 30 # "angle" de 30°
        """
    elif key == "e":
        if angle_canon > 0:
            angle_canon = (angle_canon - 1) % 30
    elif key == "z": # Bouge en avant le canon
        if move_pos_z > 1.6:
            move_pos_z -= 0.1
    elif key == "s": # Bouge en arrière le canon
        if move_pos_z < 2.0:
            move_pos_z += 0.1
    # On bouge le canon vers la droite ou la gauche
    elif key == 'd':
        if move_pos_x < 1.4:
            move_pos_x += 0.1

    elif key == 'q':
        if move_pos_x > -1.4:
            move_pos_x -= 0.1

    # Changement de caméra
    elif key == 'p':
        """
        Rotation selon l'axe Y
        """
        moveY = (moveY + 1) % 30
        glRotatef(moveY, 0, 1, 0)


    elif key == 'p':
        """
        Rotation selon l'axe X
        """
        moveX = (moveX + 1) % 100
        glRotatef(moveX, 1, 0, 0)


    elif key == 'o':
        """
        Rotation selon l'axe Z
        """

    elif key == '\033':
        sys.exit()
    glutPostRedisplay()  # indispensable en Python

def mouse(button, state, x, y):
    global pas_zoom
    if button == 3:
        print("zoom up")
        pas_zoom += 0.1
        glTranslatef(0, 0, pas_zoom)

    elif button == 4:
        print("zoom down")


def special_keyboard(key, x, y):
    global moveX, moveY, moveZ
    print(key.decode())
    if key == 103: # Fleche du bas
        pass
    elif key == 101: # Fleche du haut
        pass
    elif key == 100: # Fleche de gauche
        pass
    elif key == GLUT_KEY_RIGHT: # Fleche de droite
        print(key)
        moveY = (moveY + 1) % 100
        glRotatef(moveY, 0, 1, 0)




def reshape(width, height):
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height)
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION) # Projection orthographique
    glLoadIdentity()
    if width <= height:
           glOrtho(-2.5, 2.5, -2.5*height/width, 2.5*height/width, -10.0, 10.0)
    else:
           glOrtho(-2.5*width/height, 2.5*width/height, -2.5, 2.5, -10.0, 10.0)
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW) # On switch de type de projection

###############################################################
# MAIN

glutInit()
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH)

glutCreateWindow('CANOOOOON')
glutReshapeWindow(800,800)

glutReshapeFunc(reshape)
glutDisplayFunc(display)
glutSpecialFunc(special_keyboard)
glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard)
glutMouseFunc(mouse)



init()

glutMainLoop()


"""
A faire:
lever le fut du canon
bouger le canon avec les roues
"""
```

Comment: Yes I have tried it and nothing.
If i print something like "hey" under the if, 'hey' is printed but the camera is not moving

Comment: I'm working on Ubuntu 20.04.2 with python3

Comment: I'm working on the lastest version of pyopengl. I just updated it with pip

Comment: I got integer (102 for the right arrow, 100 for the left one..)

Comment: No the condition is True. If i print something under the `if key == 102`, it's printed

Comment: The print  s OK but the `glRotatef(moveY, 1, 0, 0)` is not and I don't know why

Comment: There is no problem elsewhere so my code is fine.
For KeyboardFunc callback, thats just mutliple `if` or `elif` but for normal key (letter or digit)
For SpecialFunc callback, that's the same but for integer (102 is for the right arrow, 101 for the up one, 100 for the left one, and 103 for the down one)

I just don't know why it's working when I'm pressing a letter (p for example) and not working when I'm pressing the right arrow

Comment: Ok I will show my entier code.
No i didnt miss the `global moveY`

Answer (score 1):

You missed to invoke `glutPostRedisplay()` after changing the current matrix:

```py
def special_keyboard(key, x, y):
    global moveX, moveY, moveZ
    #print(key.decode())
    if key == 103: # Fleche du bas
        pass
    elif key == 101: # Fleche du haut
        pass
    elif key == 100: # Fleche de gauche
        pass
    elif key == GLUT_KEY_RIGHT: # Fleche de droite
        print(key)
        moveY = (moveY + 1) % 100
        glRotatef(moveY, 0, 1, 0)#

    glutPostRedisplay()  # <--- THIS IS MISSING
```

`glutPostRedisplay` causes that the current window is redisplayed after the changes to the current matrix.

Comment: Oh thanks man. I didn't know this function (I'm new to OpenGL) and because I didnt used it for the KeyboardFunc, I didn't know I had to use it. But now this is working. Sorry to bothering you ^^

Comment: @BaptisteLeroux actually you are calling `glutPostRedisplay` at the end of the function `keyboard`

Comment: Yes i saw it but this is not my code. This is my teacher code (it's a school project) and he gave it to us (the code's skeleton)